# Cloudwatch event triggers a lambda when EBS snapshots' permissions are changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snapshot, aws-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set up a cloudwatch event that triggers a lambda when the permissions on the EBS snapshot are changed.
For now, the cloudwatch event is limited to the following:

createSnapshot 
copySnapshot 
shareSnapshot

But obviously, by using any of these, my Lambda is not triggered.

This is the event pattern I am currently using:

```
{
  "source": [
  "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
  "EBS Snapshot Notification"
  ]
 }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how the venet patten should look like to trigger my Lambda on a a change on the Permissions?